# Cant figure out how to implement a 3 strike feature in Javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to allow the user to make 2 mistakes before they lose the game. I need to:

**-Create a global variable to track the number of mistakes**

**-Initialize that variable during startGame**

**-Edit the guess function so that it updates the mistake counter when the user makes and mistake, and adds a check of that variable before calling the loseGame function**

Im having trouble implementing this into the JS file. How can I do it?

JS File:

```
const cluePauseTime = 333; //how long to pause in between clues
const nextClueWaitTime = 1000; //how long to wait before starting playback of the clue sequence

//Global variables
var clueHoldTime = 200; //how long to hold each clue's light/sound
// var pattern = [2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5];
var pattern = [];
var clueLength = 10;
///////////////////////////////
var progress = 0;
var gamePlaying = false;
var tonePlaying = false;
var volume = 0.5;
var guessCounter = 0;

function startGame() {
  progress = 0;

  pattern = []; // reset so array doesn't get longer then 10 if we restart game
  for (var i = 0; i < clueLength; i++) {
    pattern.push(getRandomInt(5));
  }
  console.log("pattern: " + pattern);

  gamePlaying = true;

  document.getElementById("startBtn").classList.add("hidden");
  document.getElementById("stopBtn").classList.remove("hidden");

  playClueSequence();
}

function stopGame() {
  gamePlaying = false;

  document.getElementById("startBtn").classList.remove("hidden");
  document.getElementById("stopBtn").classList.add("hidden");
}

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max) + 1);
}

function lightButton(btn) {
  document.getElementById("button" + btn).classList.add("lit");
}
function clearButton(btn) {
  document.getElementById("button" + btn).classList.remove("lit");
}

function playSingleClue(btn) {
  if (gamePlaying) {
    lightButton(btn);
    playTone(btn, clueHoldTime);
    setTimeout(clearButton, clueHoldTime, btn);
  }
}

function playClueSequence() {
  guessCounter = 0;
  let delay = nextClueWaitTime; //set delay to initial wait time
  for (let i = 0; i <= progress; i++) {
    // for each clue that is revealed so far
    console.log("play single clue: " + pattern[i] + " in " + delay + "ms");
    setTimeout(playSingleClue, delay, pattern[i]); // set a timeout to play that clue
    delay += clueHoldTime;
    delay += cluePauseTime;
  }
}

function loseGame() {
  stopGame();
  alert("Game Over. You lost.");
}
function winGame() {
  stopGame();
  alert("Yayyyyy, you win!!");
}

function guess(btn) {
  console.log("user guessed: " + btn);
  if (!gamePlaying) {
    return;
  }
  if (pattern[guessCounter] == btn) {
    if (guessCounter == progress) {
      if (progress == pattern.length - 1) {
        winGame();
      } else {
        progress++;
        playClueSequence();
      }
    } else {
      guessCounter++;
    }
    //guessCounter++;
  } else {
    loseGame();
  }
}
// Sound Synthesis Functions
const freqMap = {
  1: 261.6,
  2: 329.6,
  3: 392,
  4: 466.2,
  5: 432.8,
  6: 336.2
};
function playTone(btn, len) {
  o.frequency.value = freqMap[btn];
  g.gain.setTargetAtTime(volume, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
  tonePlaying = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    stopTone();
  }, len);
}
function startTone(btn) {
  if (!tonePlaying) {
    o.frequency.value = freqMap[btn];
    g.gain.setTargetAtTime(volume, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
    tonePlaying = true;
  }
}
function stopTone() {
  g.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
  tonePlaying = false;
}

//Page Initialization
// Init Sound Synthesizer
var context = new AudioContext();
var o = context.createOscillator();
var g = context.createGain();
g.connect(context.destination);
g.gain.setValueAtTime(0, context.currentTime);
o.connect(g);
o.start(0);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Hello!</title>

    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Memory Game</h1>

    <p>
      Welcome to the game that will test your memory!
    </p>

    <button id="startBtn" onclick="startGame()">
      Start
    </button>
    <button id="stopBtn" class="hidden" onclick="stopGame()">
      Stop
    </button>

    <div id="gameButtonArea">
      <button
        id="button1"
        onclick="guess(1)"
        onmousedown="startTone(1)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      ></button>
      <button
        id="button2"
        onclick="guess(2)"
        onmousedown="startTone(2)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      ></button>
      <button
        id="button3"
        onclick="guess(3)"
        onmousedown="startTone(3)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      ></button>
      <button
        id="button4"
        onclick="guess(4)"
        onmousedown="startTone(4)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      ></button>
      <button
        id="button5"
        onclick="guess(5)"
        onmousedown="startTone(5)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      ></button>
      <button
        id="button6"
        onclick="guess(6)"
        onmousedown="startTone(6)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      ></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 2em;
  background-color: slategrey;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  color: yellow;
}

button {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#gameButtonArea > button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#button1 {
  background: lightgreen;
}
#button1:active,
#button1.lit {
  background: green;
}

#button2 {
  background: lightblue;
}
#button2:active,
#button2.lit {
  background: blue;
}

#button3 {
  background: pink;
}
#button3:active,
#button3.lit {
  background: red;
}

#button4 {
  background: lightyellow;
}
#button4:active,
#button4.lit {
  background: yellow;
}

#button5 {
  background: lightgray;
}
#button5:active,
#button5.lit {
  background: black;
}

#button6 {
  background: white;
}
#button6:active,
#button6.lit {
  background: purple;
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question/problem? You've told us what you need, but not what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a variable `let lostCount = 0;`.
2. Change guess else block to:

```
else {
    if (lostCount < 2) lostCount++;
    else loseGame();
 }
```

---

```
const cluePauseTime = 333; //how long to pause in between clues
const nextClueWaitTime = 1000; //how long to wait before starting playback of the clue sequence

//Global variables
var clueHoldTime = 200; //how long to hold each clue's light/sound
// var pattern = [2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5];
var pattern = [];
var clueLength = 10;
///////////////////////////////
var progress = 0;
var gamePlaying = false;
var tonePlaying = false;
var volume = 0.5;
var guessCounter = 0;

let lostCount = 0;

function startGame() {
  progress = 0;

  pattern = []; // reset so array doesn't get longer then 10 if we restart game
  for (var i = 0; i < clueLength; i++) {
    pattern.push(getRandomInt(5));
  }
  console.log("pattern: " + pattern);

  gamePlaying = true;

  document.getElementById("startBtn").classList.add("hidden");
  document.getElementById("stopBtn").classList.remove("hidden");

  playClueSequence();
}

function stopGame() {
  gamePlaying = false;

  document.getElementById("startBtn").classList.remove("hidden");
  document.getElementById("stopBtn").classList.add("hidden");
}

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max) + 1);
}

function lightButton(btn) {
  document.getElementById("button" + btn).classList.add("lit");
}
function clearButton(btn) {
  document.getElementById("button" + btn).classList.remove("lit");
}

function playSingleClue(btn) {
  if (gamePlaying) {
    lightButton(btn);
    playTone(btn, clueHoldTime);
    setTimeout(clearButton, clueHoldTime, btn);
  }
}

function playClueSequence() {
  guessCounter = 0;
  let delay = nextClueWaitTime; //set delay to initial wait time
  for (let i = 0; i <= progress; i++) {
    // for each clue that is revealed so far
    console.log("play single clue: " + pattern[i] + " in " + delay + "ms");
    setTimeout(playSingleClue, delay, pattern[i]); // set a timeout to play that clue
    delay += clueHoldTime;
    delay += cluePauseTime;
  }
}

function loseGame() {
  stopGame();
  alert("Game Over. You lost.");
}
function winGame() {
  stopGame();
  alert("Yayyyyy, you win!!");
}

function guess(btn) {
  console.log("user guessed: " + btn);
  if (!gamePlaying) {
    return;
  }
  if (pattern[guessCounter] == btn) {
    if (guessCounter == progress) {
      if (progress == pattern.length - 1) {
        winGame();
      } else {
        progress++;
        playClueSequence();
      }
    } else {
      guessCounter++;
    }
    //guessCounter++;
  } else {
    if (lostCount < 2) lostCount++;
    else loseGame();
  }
}
// Sound Synthesis Functions
const freqMap = {
  1: 261.6,
  2: 329.6,
  3: 392,
  4: 466.2,
  5: 432.8,
  6: 336.2,
};
function playTone(btn, len) {
  o.frequency.value = freqMap[btn];
  g.gain.setTargetAtTime(volume, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
  tonePlaying = true;
  setTimeout(function () {
    stopTone();
  }, len);
}
function startTone(btn) {
  if (!tonePlaying) {
    o.frequency.value = freqMap[btn];
    g.gain.setTargetAtTime(volume, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
    tonePlaying = true;
  }
}
function stopTone() {
  g.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
  tonePlaying = false;
}

//Page Initialization
// Init Sound Synthesizer
var context = new AudioContext();
var o = context.createOscillator();
var g = context.createGain();
g.connect(context.destination);
g.gain.setValueAtTime(0, context.currentTime);
o.connect(g);
o.start(0);
```

Comment: I understand what you did but when incorporating it into the code, it works the first round but after pressing start multiple times after for multiple rounds, the game doesn't use the 2 strikes.

Comment: Are you resetting `lostCount` inside the function that restarts the game?